# Find all solutions for a complex equation: $(1+i)z^2 - (6+i)z + 9+7i=0$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

There is this math assignment that we've been given to find all the answers for some diffrent math problems.

The problem is: $(1+i)z^2 - (6+i)z + 9+7i=0$, find all the solutions and answer in geometric form.

I've tried the following:

$(1+i)z^2 - (6+i)z + 9 + 7i = 0 $

$z^2 - ((6+i)*(1-i)z) + ((9+7i)*(1-i)) = 0$ //Leaves $z^2$ by itself.

$z^2 - (7-5i)z + (16-2i) = 0$

$z^2 - (7-5i)z + ((7-5i)/2)^2 - ((7-5i)/2)^2 + (16-2i) = 0$ //completing the square

$(z - ((7-5i)/2))^2 - ((7-5i)/2)^2 + (16-2i) = 0$

Have I done something wrong? And how should I proceed?

Alright, after some recalculations, I reach this:

$$(z-((7-5i)/2))^2 - ((7-5i)^2)/4 + (32-4i)/4 = 0$$

$$(z-((7-5i)/2))^2 - (56-4i)/4 = 0$$

Comment: $(1+i)(1-i)=1+1=2$, and not $1$ (first line).

Comment: It looks like you have the equation in the form $(z-A)^2 - B = 0$ for some $A, B \in \Bbb{C}$. Now, doesn't this imply $z = A \pm \sqrt{B}$?

Answer (score 1):

$$(1+i)z^2-(6+i)z+9+7i=0\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

Use the abc-formula:

---

$$z=\frac{-\left(-(6+i)\right)\pm\sqrt{\left(-(6+i)\right)^2-4\cdot\left(1+i\right)\cdot\left(9+7i\right)}}{2\cdot\left(1+i\right)}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$z=\frac{-\left(-6-i\right)\pm\sqrt{\left(-6-i\right)^2-4\cdot\left(1+i\right)\cdot\left(9+7i\right)}}{2+2i}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$z=\frac{\left(6+i\right)\pm\sqrt{\left(35+12i\right)-4\cdot\left(1+i\right)\cdot\left(9+7i\right)}}{2+2i}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$z=\frac{\left(6+i\right)\pm\sqrt{\left(35+12i\right)-4\cdot\left(2+16i\right)}}{2+2i}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$z=\frac{\left(6+i\right)\pm\sqrt{\left(35+12i\right)-\left(8+64i\right)}}{2+2i}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$z=\frac{\left(6+i\right)\pm\sqrt{27-52i}}{2+2i}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$z=\frac{6+i}{2+2i}\pm\frac{1}{2+2i}\sqrt{27-52i}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$z=\left(\frac{7}{4}-\frac{5}{4}i\right)\pm\left(\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{4}i\right)\sqrt{27-52i}$$